# stoping a yoyo() Tween within a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, tween

I am wanting to stop this yoyo movement when a sound stops.

This is not all the code but the important parts:

I DECLARED THE VAR OUTSIDE OF THE FUNCTION:

```
var BB:Tween;
```

........

```
function BounceBeau()
{
    var BB:Tween = new Tween(Beau,"y",Strong.easeOut,stage.stageHeight - BeauHeight,33,5,false);
    BB.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, PlayBB);
    function PlayBB(e:TweenEvent):void 
               {
        BB.yoyo();
           }

}
```

THE BOUNCE STARTS WITH SOUND AND STOPS WHEN OVER.

```
function PlaySound()
{

    var ThemeSong:SoundChannel;
    var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("MySound.mp3"));
    ThemeSong = s.play();
```

...

```
BounceBeau();
```

...

```
    ThemeSong.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete); 
    function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event):void
        {
        BounceBeauStop();
        }
}
```

...
**THIS CODE WAS IN BUT I FORGOT TO POST IT**

```
function BounceBeauStop()
{
BB.stop();
}
```

THE ERROR I GET:
**TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.**

Any Thoughts. :)

Comment: on which line do you get that error? Have you tried actually _debugging_ your code line by line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `BounceBeau()`, change `var BB:Tween` to just `BB`. You are inadvertently shadowing the declaration of `BB` by redeclaring it locally.

```
function BounceBeau()
{
    BB = new Tween( ...
    ...
```

Comment: not sure how to write this line. I googled it but could not find anything. Can you show me what you mean with a full line? Thanks so much.

Comment: THAT WAS IT. Amazing. I LOVE this site. It should be called GENEROSITY-OVERFLOW.COM :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you get that error here:

```
var ThemeSong:SoundChannel;
var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("MySound.mp3"));
ThemeSong = s.play();
```

Because you are not instantiating a new `SoundChannel` variable. Then, when you try to play the sound, and pass it to the channel, the latter one is not defined. I think you should try updating your code this way:

```
var themeSong:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("MySound.mp3"));
themeSong = s.play();
```

Let us know if it works out. Have a great day.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. However it didn't work. I do believe its a problem with the BB.stop(); because I remove it and the code works fine. It calls traces etc... but I add that and BAM. :( I know its a VAR scope issue... well I believe. :/

Comment: There is no BB.stop or BounceBeauStop method in your question, so it's hard to guess an answer. Try adding that as well, so we can get a better idea regarding the code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. BB.stop(); is referring the TWEEN I created. It's supposed to stop it. BounceBeauStop() is a function I created. I will update the code. I see I didn't add them. So sorry.